# TypeScript service worker showing error: "Property 'register' does not exist on type 'unknown'"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, service-worker

I'm trying to register a service worker in a Next.js / React app using typescript, but the call to navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js') is showing the error: "Property 'register' does not exist on type 'unknown'".

I tried updating typescript, and tried explicitly setting the type for both the navigator and serviceWorker objects, but none resolved the error.

Here is the code for the React component that is registering the service worker:

```
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'
import { useEffect } from 'react'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  useEffect(() => {
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js')
    }
  }, []);
  
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

export default MyApp
```

The package.json file:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "latest",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.14",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.5",
    "typescript": "4.7.4"
  }
}
```

And the tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve"
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```